# How can I echo an array of values from a php mySQL query?

Tags: php, authentication

Basically I am attempting to make a login. I understand a very small amount of php, but everytime I try to log in it works. So it is not following my if statement below. So I would like to see if anyone can help me print the $results as not a string. Everytime I echo it, it says error can not print as string. Which makes me think its an array, can someone help ? =(

```
<?php
include('include/dbConnection.php');

if (isset($_REQUEST['attempt']))
{
    //variables
    $user = $_POST['user'];
    $password = sha1($_POST['password']);

    //SQL statement
    $query = "SELECT COUNT(user) 
              FROM users
              WHERE user = '$user'
              AND password = '$password'";

    //Execute prepared MySQL statement
    $results = mysqli_query($dbc,$query) or die('Error querying database');
        /* Here is where I want to print $results

    if ($results = 1)
    {
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['$user'];
        header('location: home.php');
    }
    else
    {
        echo $results + 'Incorrect Username or Password';
    }

*/
    //Close dbConnect
    mysqli_close($dbc);
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `var_dump($output)` or `print_r($output)` to display contents of an array.

Comment: beyond the fact that there's no $output in the OP's question, it does not at all answer how to get the results of the query.

Comment: If the OP cannot figure out to replace $output with his/her own variable, then we have a bigger problem.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use this:

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($results);
echo "</pre>";
```

It first echoes  so that the print of the array is formatted properly. If you don't do this it will all be on one line.

Hope this helped! :D

Answer (score 0):

mysql_query() returns a statement result handle, NOT the data you've requested in the query. You first have to fetch a row of data to get access to the actual query data:

```
$result = mysqli_query(...);

$row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
$count = $row[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

mysqli_query function returns false for unsuccessful queries. it returns a MySQLi_Result object for select or show queries and true for insert and update queries.

if your query fails for some reason your script will die because of `or die` statement and never returns false.

```
if ($results = 1)
```

statement assigns 1 to your result variable. when your script runs, your code enters this if block. because you control the assignment statement whether it is done or not.

your query is a select, mysqli_query function returns MySQLi_Result object.

Comment: But I want to check to see if username exists, by doing a select count(user) where user = '$user'. Which should be 1 or 0. thats why I put that if statement there

Comment: select count(user) is also a select statement indeed. MySQLi_Result object must be returned from mysqli_query. you can control number of rows returned by the query instead of controlling true value by using if($result->num_rows >=1).